# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome while loading jQuery DataTable server side

Tags: ajax, datatables

Related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281489/how-to-populate-a-jquery-datatable-using-server-side-processing-php), I'm getting this error (`F12 > Network`) while trying to load a jQuery DataTable in Chrome.

> Failed to load resource: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The table doesn't load any data. Although it doesn't work in other browsers either. I already disabled all the extensions (AdBlock included) but still nothing. Maybe is something related to internet options in Windows?

Comment: You should provide more information

Comment: You need to include some code, so we can take a look. This could be caused by so many different things including many not related to DataTables.

Comment: Alright. The issue was my apache server wasn't up (yes, I'm stupid) and the CORS requests weren't allowed. Thanks both of you.